# Suppose that $\{a_n\}$ is a geometric progression satisfying $a_1+a_2+a_3=14$ and $a_2+a_3+a_4=-42$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Suppose that $\{a_n\}$ is a geometric progression satisfying $a_1+a_2+a_3=14$ and $a_2+a_3+a_4=-42$. I'm trying to find both $a_1$ and the common ratio $r$.

My attempt:

$-42=S_4-a_1=\frac{a_1(1-r^4)}{1-r}$

$14=S_3=\frac{a_1(1-r^3)}{1-r}$

Dividing the top equation by the bottom leads us to:

$-3 = \frac{1-r^4}{1-r^3}$

Is this all correct so far? If so, can somebody help me proceed? I'm a bit stuck. Also, if there are alternative methods, please share!

Thanks, I really appreciate everyone's help!

Comment: One observation - you should confirm that you have $r\neq 1$ before using these formulae. Also you don't need to use the sum formulae in this way - just using what you get by substituting $ar^{n-1}$ for the $n^{th}$ term and dividing thorough will eliminate $a$ in just the way you have done, but clearing fractions will give you a cubic, rather than a quartic with the spurious extra root $r=1$.

Comment: @Frogwilldo In your solution you forgot about $-a_1$ in $S_4-a_1$.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu I see, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint : $a_{n+1}=ra_n$. Then?

> $$-3=\frac{-42}{14}=\frac{a_2+a_3+a_4}{a_1+a_2+a_3}=\frac{ra_1+ra_2+ra_3}{a_1+a_2+a_3}=r\\\ \\\ \\14=a_1+a_2+a_3=a_1+(-3)a_1+(-3)^2a_1=7a_1,\ \ \  a_1=2$$